# Where is Posted Data in HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am posting Json data to a Restful Api.

The server ASP.Net MVC app automatically binds the data to a model object using JsonValueProviderFactory

```
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Student")]
public ActionResult PutStudent(Student s)
{
    return Content("");
}
```

Only some of the json data is bound to Student. Others are not. In the MVC app, how do I see the raw posted data? I am unable to find it in HttpContext.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try reading the stream in `HttpContext.Request.InputStream` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to inspect the raw HTTP traffic.

Comment: Fiddler functionality is basically built into Chrome and Firebug now also.

Comment: @NickLarsen, who said that the client is a browser? Of course if it is, FireBug is the way to go.